# MVC6 Web Project Grunt Start Debugging

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a web project which is using the next version of MVC. I have a gruntfile setup and was hoping to set it up to start debugging (F5) for me. Is there a plugin to do this or has this not been done yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "prepare": ["grunt"] in your scripts inside of the project.json